# Line break broken for headers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, editor

If I have a file link for instance or any other text without spaces that is longer than the text box, it should be automatically line-broken.

> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll

But if it is a header of any form it does not work

### file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll

## file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: ([Screen capture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FPUgf.png) for future reference.)

Comment: Works on mobile site...

Comment: This might be true, and it might be worth fixing since it's a relatively low-impact fix, but I can't help but thinking that **if this happens to you, you're doing it wrong**.

Comment: @CodyGray: I agree. But it happens. I saw it in a new user`s question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be pushed out in the next build.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it needs some extra CSS... Looks like this would do the trick (in the context of questions and answers).

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

### EDIT

Interesting... It appears to [wrap lines just fine in Firefox (20)](https://i.imgur.com/FdOrsTC.png), but [not in the most recent version of Chrome](https://i.imgur.com/80H7o2H.png). The code above does fix the issue in Chrome, however.

Comment: Can confirm this is broken in mobile safari 6.0 on the full site... Testing mobile now.

Comment: Mobile site works fine - some CSS rules must be different.